# $C_1+2.5C_2 +3.5^2C_3 +\cdots n.5^{n-1}C_n = ? $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, combinations

Problem : 
$C_1+2.5C_2 +3.5^2C_3 +\cdots n.5^{n-1}C_n = ? $

My approach :

$C_1+2.5C_2 +3.5^2C_3 +\cdots C_n  = \sum_{n=1}^n n.5^n C_n$

Also $C_0+C_1+C_2+\cdots C_n = 2^n$ 
Please suggest how to move further will be of great help. Thanks

Comment: This sum is equal to $n(1 + 5)^{n-1}$

Comment: @Shailesh can you give the details please will be of great help thanks

Comment: @Shailesh I guess his "." means decimal point instead of multiplication?

Comment: I'm not sure it is exactly that, and I do not have time currently, but you can show by expanding the RHS that $C_1 + 2C_2 + 3C_3x^2 + ... nC_nx^{n-1} = n(1 + x)^{n-1}$. There is a neat trick to derive that too.

Comment: @mastrokNo, not at all

Comment: I dont think so tHat combinations are done for fractions. So it has to be multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$S=1\cdot 5^0\binom{n}{1}+2\cdot 5^1 \binom{n}{2}+3\cdot 5^2\binom{n}{3}+4\cdot 5^3\binom{n}{4}+........+n\cdot 5^{n-1}\binom{n}{n}$$

So we get $$S=\sum^{n}_{r=1}r\cdot 5^{r-1}\binom{n}{r}$$

Now Using $$\bullet\; (1+x)^n = \sum^{n}_{r=1}\binom{n}{r}x^r$$

Now Differentiate both side w. r to $x\;,$ We get

$$\bullet\; n(1+x)^{n-1} = \sum^{n}_{r=1}rx^{r-1}\binom{n}{r}$$

Now Put $x=5$ on both side of the equation, We get

$$n(1+5)^{n-1}=\sum^{n}_{r=1}r\cdot 5^{r-1}\binom{n}{r}\Rightarrow \sum^{n}_{r=1}r\cdot 5^{r-1}\binom{n}{r}=n(6)^{n-1}$$